# How to Style Complex Text

Tags: html, css, sass

So I have a task to make html/css from a PSD. Below is the reference image.

[image: Reference Image]

I have struggled mightily over the past 24 hours to make this work. What I'm fighting against is that the spacing on these large fonts is causing some very weird padding issues. I have tried a few different avenues.

Export the text or the whole thing as a PNG, the quality just isn't there. Fonts look blurry, jagged etc.

**1. Using Negative Margin**

This worked for the most part. I size "Sale", "Up to", "25", and "% Off" to the correct font size and use negative margin to get the vertical spacing correct. The problem with this approach is that I still have too much space above the text pushing the white background to being too large.

**2. Trying to Get Font Line Height Correct.**

From reading now, line height is not synonymous with 'leading' from print design. Changing the line height just appears to make a mess of things.

**3. Make Line Height fit text exactly**

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-tame-line-height-in-css/) has an article about using some SASS mixins to create a line-height that perfect matches to where the text is actually showing. Unfortunately, the font being used is Myriad Pro and I haven't found a way to get some of the data points that the mixin uses for this specific font.

**TLDR**
How should I attack this? Should I keep plugging along using negative margin, give up and just absolutely position everything, try harder to make line-height work the way I want it to? What I'm after is not just the way to make this work, but what is the correct/best way to achieve what I want.

Other Things:

1. I am using typekit to supply the fonts.
2. I read something about SVG or SVG fonts. Would it make sense to just form the text as SVGs so they are easy to manipulate? (Again, looking for a best practice).
3. Below is a snippet that just has a base setup for experimenting.
4. Intersing article here [about using fonts inside an svg](https://css-tricks.com/using-custom-fonts-with-svg-in-an-image-tag/). This might work.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/toj1dxz.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l19aL.png" alt="Ref" width="315" height="147" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use an SVG or a plain ol' PNG image instead of HTML & CSS? Seems like the client likely would not care.

Comment: Plain ol Png was my initial, sorry didn't put that in post. The text quality was way too poor. I am in the process of trying SVG as outlineed in pt. 4 right now. Also updated my post.

Comment: I was *about* to suggest using your webfonts inside an SVG, but unfortunately I ran into two walls trying it out: a) SVG's loading using `<img>` cannot pull in resources such as stylesheets or WOFF2 fonts. b) It doesn't apply the font face to elements inside the SVG that reference fonts defined in the HTML document, again when loaded via `<img>`.

Comment: Yep, so in this article mentioned in #4 I ended up using their 'nano' tool to embed the fonts directly into the SVG (Export SVG from Illustrator with inline styles, run through nano). This has gotten as close as I think I can. Thanks for trying and pointing towards SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

I used SVGs with embedded fonts using [Nano from Vecta.io](https://vecta.io/nano). The below snippet isn't perfect but with a few tweaks I was able to make it size correctly without having to deal with margins/padding/line-height and font loading.

The best part is that the 2 SVGs don't even break a kb of data.

As a side note, I don't know why the embedded Myriad Pro is different than the one in photoshop but the similarities are good enough.

```css
.redWrapper {
  background-color: #D40011;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }
 
 .sale {
   width: 177px;
   height: 152px;
   img {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
 
 .twoFive {
   width: 237px;
   height: 195px;
   img {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/toj1dxz.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h6>SVG w/ Embedded Font using Nano</h6>
        <div class="redWrapper">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sale">
              <img src='https://svgshare.com/i/10mv.svg' title='sale' />
            </div>
            <div class="twoFive">
              <img src='https://svgshare.com/i/10me.svg' title='twofive' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6>Reference</h6>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l19aL.png" alt="Ref" width="315" height="147" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be careful: nano can only embed google fonts (and maybe some other publically available cdn) fonts. It can't fetch local fonts from your device and create a data URL. That's why your svg files are quite small. If you don't need to update the numbers dynamically you can rebuild this label also in a graphic app like inkscape - which is probably way more intuitive. Besides graphic apps aloow you to convert text to paths - so you dont't need to embed font files.

Comment: You are very right! Thanks